# Cordova on Mac OSX: issues with a network project folder (Windows)

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, networking, directory

I have this scenario where all my Cordova projects are stored on a Windows machine. In Windows I work with the Android platform, which works with no problem.

For the iOS platform I work on a Mac OSX (High Sierra), accessing the project folders (in Windows) via network shared folder (I need to avoid the duplication of project files/folders). In Mac I can browse the Windows files accesing the mounted drive (/Volumes/PROJECTS) which I connected to using an authorized user account that exists on Windows ("spacorum", with administrator rights).

From the Mac terminal I can create a new Project, which is perfectly stored on the Windows shared folder. Then, after entering the new created project folder, I try to add the ios platform and the process never ends, it doesn´t do anything and no "ios" folder is created under "/platforms".

This is the output I get running "**cordova platform add ios -d**":

```
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
Grabbing pinned version.
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4
saving
```

I must cancel it or it freezes like this for days. 
But Cordova works fine, I checked it because if I do the same steps on a local folder (stored on the Mac OSX, not in Windows via networking), the process ends as expected:

```
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
Grabbing pinned version.
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4
saving
Running command: npm install cordova-ios@~4.5.4 --production --save
Command finished with error code 0: npm install,cordova-ios@~4.5.4,--production,--save
Removing "cordova-" prefix from cordova-ios
Adding ios project...
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.example.hello
    Name: Hello
Copying iOS template project to /Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.5
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios/Hello/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/exec.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/exec.js (new file)
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/platform.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/platform.js (new file)
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/plugin
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/plugin/ios
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/plugin/ios/console.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/plugin/ios/console.js (new file)
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/plugin/ios/logger.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/plugin/ios/logger.js (new file)
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova.js platforms/ios/www/cordova.js (updated file)
  copy  www/index.html platforms/ios/www/index.html (updated file)
  copy  www/js/index.js platforms/ios/www/js/index.js (updated file)
Current launch storyboard undefined
Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.example.hello" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios/Hello/Hello-Info.plist
No need to update build settings for launch storyboard support.
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "Hello")
This app does not have icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/Hello/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" following successful platform add of ios
Found variables for "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Processing as cli_variables.
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Running command: "/Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios/cordova/version" 
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios/Hello/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova_plugins.js platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js (updated file)
Current launch storyboard undefined
Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.example.hello" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/spacorum/Desktop/test projects/Hello/platforms/ios/Hello/Hello-Info.plist
No need to update build settings for launch storyboard support.
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "Hello")
This app does not have icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/ios/Hello/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
Saving ios@4.5.5 into platforms.json
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving ios@~4.5.5 into config.xml file ...
adding ios to cordova.platforms array in package.json
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
```

If this is permissions problem, I don´t know how to solve it. The Windows shared folder has full access, and I´m logged as the authorized user. Also, I was able to create the project, I doubt I could do it if I didn´t have the rights from Mac, right?

Note: I noticed that if I list the folders shared from Windows on a Mac terminal (ls -la) every folder has "700" as the default permission, and I cannot change it using chmod, nothing changes. On the other way, the local projects folder I have on Mac has every subfolder with more permissions (755), and I can change it with chmod with no problem.

Not a heavy *nix user, so any help would be appreciated, I´ve been stuck here for a week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to appear when launching the command:

```
npm install cordova-ios@~4.5.4 --production --save
```

The output when launching it with debug flag on Mac OSX from the Cordova workspace (located on the Windows shared folder) is this:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.3.0
npm info using node@v10.7.0
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios 361ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 3628ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 4ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 22ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 3624ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 3720ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 572ms
npm timing audit compress Completed in 13ms
npm info audit Submitting payload of 1190bytes
npm timing audit submit Completed in 1095ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 1092ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 2ms
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/package.json'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/.eslintignore'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/.eslintrc.yml'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/.gitattributes'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/.istanbul.yml'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/.ratignore'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/.travis.yml'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/appveyor.yml'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/component.json'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/CONTRIBUTING.md'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/LICENSE'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/NOTICE'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/README.md'
WARN tar EIO: i/o error, open '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/.staging/cordova-ios-5086fba7/RELEASENOTES.md'
⸨       ░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ extract:cordova-ios: timing audit body Completed in 2ms
```

Instead, the output when running on the local workspace located in Mac OSX is good:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.3.0
npm info using node@v10.7.0
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios 75ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 2096ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 3ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 259ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pegjs 1121ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 5389ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 5740ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 47ms
npm timing audit compress Completed in 11ms
npm info audit Submitting payload of 1244bytes
npm timing audit submit Completed in 1115ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 1114ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 2ms
npm timing action:extract Completed in 4074ms
npm info lifecycle cordova-ios@4.5.5~preuninstall: cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm info lifecycle cordova-ios@4.5.5~uninstall: cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm info lifecycle cordova-ios@4.5.5~postuninstall: cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm timing action:unbuild Completed in 22ms
npm timing action:remove Completed in 328ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 43ms
npm timing action:refresh-package-json Completed in 36ms
npm info lifecycle cordova-ios@4.5.5~preinstall: cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm timing action:preinstall Completed in 2ms
npm info linkStuff cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm timing action:build Completed in 8ms
npm info lifecycle cordova-ios@4.5.5~install: cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm timing action:install Completed in 3ms
npm info lifecycle cordova-ios@4.5.5~postinstall: cordova-ios@4.5.5
npm timing action:postinstall Completed in 3ms
npm timing stage:executeActions Completed in 5001ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 12979ms
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm WARN com.example.hello@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ cordova-ios@4.5.5
updated 1 package and audited 128 packages in 13.272s
found 0 vulnerabilities

npm timing npm Completed in 14794ms
npm info ok
```

At least I can discard network problems, also npm and cordova work fine. This seems to be a permissions issue from the Windows side, in the project "/node_modules/.staging/" subfolder. I can´t see how, as every subfolder under the parent folder "/PROJECTS" is writtable for everyone (administrators, logged users and any other users).

I tried to turn off the read-only flag in the "node_modules" subfolder in Windows, but once I reopen the dialog window, it´s enabled again.

I also tried turning off Windows 10 Firewall and Defender, with no difference.

---

**UPDATE & FIX**: Finally, a solution. I´m sharing this here in case anyone has the same scenario and issues. I found a log under "/Users/myusername/.npm-cache/_logs/" which pointed me in the right direction:

```
Error: Unknown system error -102: Unknown system error -102, symlink '../nopt/bin/nopt.js' -> '/Volumes/PROJECTS/Hello/node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/ios-sim/node_modules/.bin/nopt'
```

I read that this could be related to the OSX system being unable to create symbolic links (in WINDOWS) during the npm command launch. I used this to avoid symlink when running npm commands:

```
npm config set bin-links false
```

And this did the trick. Now the iOS platform has been added perfectly from OSX terminal, using a project folder stored remotely in a WINDOWS machine.

Case solved!